# JPA 2.1 Entity graph's subgraphs generating empty joins

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly, jpa-2.1

I am using a new feature in JPA 2.1 called [Entity Graphs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm) with [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/). It's working great. But when I use [subgraph](https://github.com/hantsy/ee7-sandbox/blob/master/jpa/entitygraph/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/example/ee7/jpa/Post.java), JPA generate invalid SQL. Here is my sample:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
     name="defaultGet",
     attributeNodes = {
          @NamedAttributeNode("client"),
          @NamedAttributeNode(value = "tests", subgraph = "testsSG")
     },
     subgraphs ={
          @NamedSubgraph(
               name="testsSG",
               attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode("template")
               }
          )
     }
)
```

Here is generated SQL:

```
select
    ...correct stuff....
from
    iq_applicant applicant0_ 
left outer join
    iq_test tests1_ 
        on applicant0_.id=tests1_.applicant 
left outer join
    iq_template template2_ 
        on tests1_.template=template2_.id cross 
join            
                            //WTF?? empty lane??
left outer join
    iq_client client3_ 
        on applicant0_.client=client3_.id
```

What is that empty lane doing in there? Is this a bug?

Comment: What exact version of WildFly / Hibernate, is your dialect properly configured? You do have latest jdbc driver?

Comment: WildFly - 8.0.0.Final,
Hibernate - 4.3.1.Final,
my dialect in persistance.xml: 
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"/>
and I am using PostGreSQL 9.3, so it's the latest.

Comment: Why don't you use org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect?

Comment: cause I didn't know there was one. Replaced, still the same issue.

Comment: I also encounter the same issue.  It probably a bug related to inheritance support in named EntityGraph.

Answer (score 1):

I guess It's Hibernate issue. There are several issues:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9175
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9392